# Swift Messaging App - Conversation UIScrollView Alignment

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiscrollview, messaging

I am building a messaging app using Swift and Parse.com.

I have been making good progress, but am having trouble getting my message bubbles to align correctly in the `UIScrollView`.

When I begin a conversation, the message aligns to the bottom of the scroller.

However, as soon as I touch the `UIScrollView`, the message(s) suddenly pop up to the top of the frame.

I think I understand why - the most recent message should align to the bottom when the entire conversation is longer than the scroller. But, when the conversation is shorter than the frame, it should align to the top (like in iMessage etc.).

I just don't know how to get it to behave like this.

Comment: Show the code you're currently using, and perhaps link to a couple of screenshots

Comment: Too many characters for pasting code here unfortunately - screenshots and code here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/aoxjkjwnh2x3d6k/AACFACFndmzJ4vfTCJnkGjPga?dl=0